# Android 6.0, my app don't work anymore when i generate release version

Tags: java, android

I have developed an app for Android, unfortunately, when I try to compile the version "release" and install it no longer works with Android 6.0 devices and up. By entering the "debugbble true" parameter, however it works, unfortunately does not allow me to publish it on playstore. Does anyone have a solution? I also added a toast startup of Activity that, unfortunately nonv hyenas even performed as the first statement. How can I do?
edit.

```
    package org.altervista.xsparter.www.IlMaestro001;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by domen on 24/09/2015.
 */
public class externalcom {
    public String urlgenerale = "http://musicalcentroarte.altervista.org/AppAndroid/Setticlavio/";
    public int errori;
    public int corrette;
    public int livello;
    public String email;
    public String chiavi;
    public boolean httpcontroller = false;
    public boolean getstatus;
    public boolean databaseonline;
    public String action;
    public String nickverifier;
    public String nickname;
    public String SettingNickname;
    public Boolean nickBOOLverifier;


    public static String getEmail(AccountManager account_service) {
        AccountManager manager = account_service;
        Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
        String gmail = null;

        for (Account account : list) {
            if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")) {
                gmail = account.name;
                break;
            }
        }

        return gmail;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() throws IOException {
        httpcontroller = false;

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                final int threadid = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
                externalcom externalcom = new externalcom();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(externalcom.urlgenerale + "getdatabaseacces.php");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader =
                                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 65728);
                        String line = null;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (sb.toString().equals("false")) {
                        getstatus = false;
                    } else if (sb.toString().equals("true")) {
                        getstatus = true;
                    }
                    httpcontroller = true;

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    getstatus = false;
                    httpcontroller = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    getstatus = false;
                    httpcontroller = true;
                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        for (int i = 0; httpcontroller == false; i++) {
            sleep(1);
            if (i == 2000) {
                t.interrupt();
                getstatus = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (getstatus == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }

    public Boolean getConnectionStatus() throws IOException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                final int threadid = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
                externalcom externalcom = new externalcom();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(externalcom.urlgenerale + "status.php");

                try {
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader =
                                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 65728);
                        String line = null;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        getstatus = false;
                        httpcontroller = true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        getstatus = false;
                        httpcontroller = true;
                    }
                    if (sb.toString().equals("true")) {
                        getstatus = true;
                        httpcontroller = true;
                    } else {
                        getstatus = false;
                        httpcontroller = true;
                    }


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    getstatus = false;
                    httpcontroller = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    getstatus = false;
                    httpcontroller = true;
                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        httpcontroller = false;
        for (int i = 0; httpcontroller == false; i++) {
            sleep(1);
            if (i == 2000) {

                t.interrupt();
                getstatus = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (getstatus == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }

    public Boolean nickIsStoraged(String nicknameTT) throws IOException {
        nickname = nicknameTT;
        httpcontroller = false;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                externalcom externalcom = new externalcom();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(externalcom.urlgenerale + "ifnick.php");
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comparenickname", nickname));
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader =
                        null;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 65728);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String line = null;

                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                nickverifier = sb.toString();
                nickBOOLverifier = Boolean.parseBoolean(nickverifier);
                httpcontroller = true;
            }
        });
        t.start();
        while (httpcontroller == false) {
        }
        return nickBOOLverifier;
    }

    public Boolean getnickname(String emailT, String nicknameTT, String actionTT) {
        email = emailT;
        nickname = nicknameTT;
        action = actionTT;
        httpcontroller = false;

        //-----------______________---------
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                externalcom externalcom = new externalcom();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(externalcom.urlgenerale + "getnick.php");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                    if (nickname == null && action == "casual") {
                        //System.err.println("Generazione nick casuale");
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("casual", "true"));
                    } else if (nickname != null && action == null) {
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname", nickname));
                    } else if (nickname == null && action == "getname" && email != null) {
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foundnick", "true"));
                    } else if (nickname != null && action == "update" && email != null) {
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("update", nickname));
                    }
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader =
                                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 65728);
                        String line = null;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    nickverifier = sb.toString();
                    if (action != "getname") {
                        nickBOOLverifier = Boolean.parseBoolean(nickverifier);
                    } else {
                        SettingNickname = nickverifier;
                        nickBOOLverifier = true;
                    }
                    httpcontroller = true;

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        while (httpcontroller == false) {

        }
        httpcontroller = false;
        return nickBOOLverifier;
    }

    public void databasememory(int erroriT, int corretteT, int livelloT, String emailT, String chiaviT) {
        errori = erroriT;
        if (errori == 0) {
            errori = 1;
        }
        corrette = corretteT;
        livello = livelloT;
        email = emailT;
        chiavi = chiaviT;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlgenerale + "databasewriter.php");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("errori", String.valueOf(errori)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("corretti", String.valueOf(corrette)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("livello", String.valueOf(livello)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("chiavi", chiavi));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        t.start();


    }

    public void sleep(int value) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(value);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This library cause the freeze of application, but it damage the app only in release mode on android 6.0+. Someone can explain why? I need this .class..

Comment: You need to provide much more details, especially what you mean with "don't work anymore". Edit your question and add sample code that fails, logcat output and so on.

Comment: I don't have any error in logcat because it don't crash, it simply stay in a "loop" showing to me a white screen. It work if i put "debuggable true" in my gradle configuration.

Comment: I have founded the library cause the "loop".